MahApps:TextBoxHelper.SelectAllOnFocus="True" doesnt work with IsAsync=true on DataGrid, WPF, . net Framework 4.8
in my WPF app (.NET Framework 4.8), there is a DataGrid that has columns with 'IsAsync=true' Binding for better performance. However, it interacts directly with the mah:DataGridHelper.EnableCellEditAssist="True", which allows the user to select all text when editing. When editing, it first selects all the fallback value, then loads the binding value, and then selects the first position of the TextBox string for editing. When I set 'IsAsync=false', it works as expected (it selects all the textbox text).
Can anyone find a workaround?
<UserControl
 ...
 xmlns:mah="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
 ...
>
...
<DataGrid
    CanUserDeleteRows="False"
    Panel.ZIndex="0"
    ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="False"
    Visibility="{Binding ShowSalesLines, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
    Grid.Column="0"
    ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentSalesLines, IsAsync=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    x:Name="SalesLinesDatagrid"
    SelectionMode="Extended"
    PreviewKeyDown="SalesLinesDatagrid_PreviewKeyDown"
    VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="True"
    EnableRowVirtualization="True"
    VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
    EnableColumnVirtualization="True"
    CanUserAddRows="False"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentSaleLine, Mode=TwoWay}"
    Style="{StaticResource MahApps.Styles.DataGrid.Azure}"
    OverridesDefaultStyle="False"
    Margin="10"
    IsReadOnly="false"
    CanUserReorderColumns="False"
    CanUserResizeRows="False"
    CanUserSortColumns="False"
    VirtualizingPanel.IsContainerVirtualizable="True"
    VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
    VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Pixel"
    SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
    VirtualizingPanel.CacheLengthUnit="Pixel"
    ScrollViewer.PanningDeceleration="5"
    >
<DataGrid.Columns>
<DataGridTextColumn
    VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
    VirtualizingPanel.IsContainerVirtualizable="True"
    VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
    Header="Prec. Unit."
    Width="auto"
    VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Pixel"
    MinWidth="75"
    mah:DataGridHelper.EnableCellEditAssist="True"
    EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource DataGridTextEditingStyle}"
    ElementStyle="{StaticResource DataGridTextColumnHorizontalRight}"
    Binding="{Binding SALESPRICE, StringFormat='0.000', ConverterCulture=es-ES, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, IsAsync=True, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, FallbackValue='0'}"
    />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
...
</UserControl>
//// Styles:
<Style
    x:Key="DataGridTextColumnHorizontalRight"
    TargetType="TextBlock"
    >
    <Setter
        Property="HorizontalAlignment"
        Value="Right"
        />
</Style>

<Style
        x:Key="DataGridTextEditingStyle"
        TargetType="TextBox"
        BasedOn="{StaticResource MahApps.Styles.TextBox.DataGrid.Editing}"
        >
        <Setter
            Property="mah:DataGridHelper.EnableCellEditAssist"
            Value="True"
            />
        <Setter
            Property="mah:TextBoxHelper.ClearTextButton"
            Value="False"
            />
</Style>

// On Viewmodel:

 private decimal _salesPrice;
 [Column(TypeName = "numeric")]
 public decimal SALESPRICE
 {
     get
     {
         return _salesPrice;
     }
     set
     {
         SetProperty(ref _salesPrice, Math.Round(value, 3, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
         OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(LINEAMOUNT)));
     }
 }

I've found no workarounds, other than mark 'IsAsync=False'
[Edit]
Actually, I found a workaround.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.notifyontargetupdated?view=windowsdesktop-8.0
This binding property allows the control to notify when the target value is updated (not necessarily loaded). You can then subscribe to the TargetUpdated event through a helper class, which triggers whenever the value is updated (synchronously or asynchronously).
It's necessary to enable NotifyOnTargetUpdated=true as its default value is false.
The helper class is:
public static class TextBoxBehavior
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectAllOnGotFocusProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "SelectAllOnGotFocus",
            typeof(bool),
            typeof(TextBoxBehavior),
            new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnSelectAllOnGotFocusChanged));

    public static bool GetSelectAllOnGotFocus(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(SelectAllOnGotFocusProperty);
    }

    public static void SetSelectAllOnGotFocus(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(SelectAllOnGotFocusProperty, value);
    }

    private static void OnSelectAllOnGotFocusChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (d is TextBox textBox)
        {
            if ((bool)e.NewValue)
            {
                textBox.GotFocus += TextBox_GotFocus;
                textBox.TargetUpdated += TextBox_TargetUpdated;
                textBox.LostFocus += TextBox_LostFocus;
            }
            else
            {
                textBox.GotFocus -= TextBox_GotFocus;
                textBox.TargetUpdated -= TextBox_TargetUpdated;
                textBox.LostFocus -= TextBox_LostFocus;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void TextBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is TextBox textBox)
        {
            textBox.SelectAll();
        }
    }

    private static void TextBox_TargetUpdated(object sender, DataTransferEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is TextBox textBox)
        {
            textBox.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                textBox.Focus();
                textBox.SelectAll();
            });
        }
    }
    private static void TextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is TextBox textBox)
        {
            textBox.GotFocus -= TextBox_GotFocus;
            textBox.TargetUpdated -= TextBox_TargetUpdated;
            textBox.LostFocus -= TextBox_LostFocus;
        }
    }
}

The Style
<Style
    x:Key="SelectAllTextBoxStyle"
    TargetType="TextBox"
    BasedOn="{StaticResource 
    MahApps.Styles.TextBox.DataGrid.Editing}"
    >
    <Setter
        Property="control:TextBoxBehavior.SelectAllOnGotFocus"
        Value="True"
        />
    <Setter
        Property="mah:TextBoxHelper.ClearTextButton"
        Value="False"
        />
</Style>

Then, you can set the binding:
<DataGridTextColumn
    VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
    VirtualizingPanel.IsContainerVirtualizable="True"
    VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
    Header="Precio Unitario"
    VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Pixel"
    EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource SelectAllTextBoxStyle}"
    Binding="{Binding SALESPRICE, StringFormat='0.000', ConverterCulture=es-ES, IsAsync=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"
    ElementStyle="{StaticResource DataGridTextColumnHorizontalRight}"
    />

As mentioned in the comments, this might not be the recommended approach, but it does address the issue of IsAsync binding conflicting with MahApps:mah:TextBoxHelper.SelectAllOnFocus=true.
(I'll be setting my bindings with IsAsync=false.)

Why do you use Binding.IsAsync at all? You should not use it as a default. Microsoft explicitly recommends against it. It's only supposed to be used for those rare cases where a property is expected to take long time to execute (which violates the Microsoft design guidelines for properties). It does not give you any performance advantage in normal use cases. The opposite is the case as asynchronous binding requires overhead. If your property returns the value fast as it should, then simply don't enable asynchronous data binding.

If you insist on configuring every binding as async, then the only solution is to implement your own  helper class, so that you have full control over the efficiency of the implementation.

By the way, the behavior you observe is the expected normal behavior of an async Binding. The Binding will first provide the Binding.FallbackValue then suspends the operation to continue as soon as the value is available. That's the asynchronous behavior of the data binding.

Not using a FallbackValue will avoid this behavior. Using Binding.TargetNullValue is more appropriate to provide a default value for the binding. But you shouldn't use async binding if it is not necessary in the first place.

@BionicCode Thanks for the atention, ill delete my Binding.IsAsync. My Binding will look something like:  Binding="{Binding SALESPRICE, StringFormat='0.000', ConverterCulture=es-ES, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"

@BionicCode By the way, I need this functionality in some special cases in DataGrid columns. These columns display properties from related tables, requiring value retrieval delays. Should I adjust my ObservableCollection query to preload these values,or modify the binding adding the IsAsync? For example, the clients table has general info linked to a tax group table with tax details. Some DataGrid fields refer to tax info not stored directly in the clients table, causing a delay in property retrieval.

My goal would be to keep the UI interaction as smooth as possible. If I had a DataGrid that is getting data from computed properties and that computations are time consuming I would compute these values once and then cache them. If you transition a cell into edit mode and this causes a delay then this means that you are computing the value for each property get call (because the value itself has not changed. Only the edit control of the DataGridCell is updating).

Fixing the way data is provided surely has more impact than an async binding. Async binding only means the UI will remain responsive. The user still has to wait. If you need help with improving the performance please be more specific on the implementation details.
